# Ссылка на метод comparing java

Tags: java

Может кто нибудь объяснить почему выражение вида:

> Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName);

вообще работает?метод comparing принимает функциональный интерфейс Function у которого метод apply принимает **1** **аргумент**.Почему ссылка на геттер getName который не принимает **никаких аргументов** вообще может быть присвоена Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Function<T, R>` - функциональный интерфейс (SAM - Single Abstract Method), с методом `R apply(T t);`, который принимает аргумент `T` и возвращает аргумент `R`. В переменную данного типа можно присвоить соответствующую функцию.

```
  // через лямда-выражение
  Function<Integer, Integer> sqr = (x) -> x * x;

  // через анонимный класс
  Function<Integer, Integer> sqr = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer x) {
            return x * x;
        }
    };
```

`Employee::getName` - ссылка на метод, но так как это не статический метод, то его нужно вызывать на объекте класса.
Так вот ссылка на метод может восприниматься как функция, принимающая объект класса, в котором происходит вызов данного метода.

Т.е. `Function<Employee, String> employeeName = Employee::getName;` тоже самое что и

```
Function<Employee, String> employeeName = (employee) -> employee.getName();

//или
Function<Employee, String> employeeName = new Function<Employee, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Employee employee) {
        return employee.getName();
    }
};
```

Именно таким типом (`Function<Employee, String>`) и будет аргумент `keyExtractor` в методе `comparing`, при передаче в него ссылки `Employee::getName`.

Comment: вот с  (employee) -> employee.getName(); мне все понятно,что в качестве  keyExtractor мы передаем Employee  и на выходе мы хотим получить getName().Но хотел уделить внимание вашей фразе "ссылка на метод может восприниматься как функция, принимающая объект класса, в котором происходит вызов данного метода." Т.е. в данном случае ссылка на метод реализуется по другому или как?В строке Employee::getName мы передаем объект класса в качестве параметра?Просто для меня ссылка на метод-это указание интерфейсу ,где именно можно взять реализацию его единственного метода.Но в данном случае,будто все иначе

Comment: @Vadya Под предложением, что вы процитировали я подразумевал `(employee) -> employee.getName()` - это и можно воспринимать (имею ввиду, что это эквивалентно `Employee::getName`) как реализацию для ссылки `Employee::getName` и то, что передаётся в функцию `comparing`. Сам объект `employee` будет передан компаратору (например в функции `sort`), а компаратор передаст той функции, что мы передали в `comparing`.

Comment: меня просто все больше смущает правило "При этом методы, на которые идет ссылка, должны совпадать по параметрам и результату с методом функционального интерфейса."И я вот никак не увижу эту связь с параметрами.В любом случае спасибо

Comment: UPD:кажется,как я понял,вся суть в том,что сам метод getName все-таки принимает параметр employee,ток неявно

Comment: @Vadya не очень понял, что вы подразумеваете под неявно неявно, `Function<Employee, String> employeeName = Employee::getName;` `String name = employeeName.apply(employee);`, по-моему очень даже явно. Просто нет такого типа как `Employee::getName`, там вроде бы происходит конвертация в анонимный класс (как в ответе в примере)

Comment: я имею ввиду то,чтобы ссылка на метод getName вообще могла передаваться в Function(который в свою очередь ждет аргумент вида Employee),нужно чтобы  getName принимал аргумент точно такой же как и apply->employee.И я вот нашел статью про неявную передачу в getName ссылки this,т.е. экземпляра класса Employee,и именно поэтому все работает, т.к. и там и там у нас есть 1 аргумент.Если я все правильно понял